# Use state causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to show a component and hide another based on a click event. However, I'm getting this error saying there is an infinite loop.

this is my code

```
 const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

 const [showPage , setShowPage] = useState(true);
```

```
 {showPage &&(
        <div>
      <FormContent>
        <Form 
              onSubmit={
                handleSubmit((data, e) => {
                try {
                  console.log(data);
                  setShowPage(false);
                  e.preventDefault();
                  //submit(data); 
                } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
        })}>
        </Form>
      </FormContent>
      </div>
      )}
      {!showPage &&(
        <ForthPage />
      )}
```

and this is the error i'm getting

`Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

```
  49 | onSubmit={handleSubmit((data, e) => {
  50 |   try {
  51 |     console.log(data);
> 52 |     setShowPage(false);
     | ^  53 |     e.preventDefault();
  54 |     //submit(data); 
  55 |   } catch (err) {
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code

Comment: Post the full component

Comment: Post the full component, and  what is `submit()` referring to?, `handleSubmit` should be a `callBack function`., and `showPage ? <A/>:<B/>` should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
onSubmit={()=>{
    handleSubmit((data, e) => {
        try {
            console.log(data);
            setShowPage(false);
            e.preventDefault();
            //submit(data); 
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        })
    }
}
```

If you want to call function or execution in onSubmit or any onClick function, you should use arrow function.