# Create user account in firebase authentication account by using createUserWithEmailAndPassword got callstack exceed error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Here I attached part of my code.

```
import FormInput from "../components/formInput";
import { auth, database } from "../firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, update } from "firebase/database";

const SignupScreen = () => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});
  const handleChange = (label, value) => {
    const newUserInfo = { ...userInfo, [label]: value };
    setUserInfo(newUserInfo);
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userInfo.Email, userInfo.Password)
      .then(() => {
       console.log('h');
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../../assets/background.jpg")}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={styles.image}
      >
        <View style={styles.logoContent}>
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/logo.png")}
            style={styles.logo}
          ></Image>
          <Text style={styles.logoText}>Branch - Chat</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.formContent}>
          <FormInput labelName="UserName" onChange={handleChange} />
          <FormInput labelName="Email" onChange={handleChange} />
          <FormInput labelName="Password" onChange={handleChange} />
          <FormInput labelName="Confirm" onChange={handleChange} />
          <Button
            label={"Sign up"}
            backgroundColor={Colors.green20}
            style={{ width: 300, marginBottom: 20, opacity: 0.7 }}
            onPress={handleSubmit}
          />
          <Link to={{ screen: "Signin" }} style={{ color: Colors.green1 }}>
            Sign in
          </Link>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SignupScreen;
```

I tried to create an account on Firebase.

When I click the Signup button, everything works well. But I got maximum callstack size exceed error.

I couldn't find what is the issue on my code.
Please help me to figure it out.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You need to prevent the default behavior for a form as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244708/use-state-causes-infinite-loop

Comment: I am afraid, It is not correct. @FrankvanPuffelen.